# Per hour Holt-Winter time series prediction (forecasting)

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, forecasting

I am fairly new to the R package and I am dealing with time series. I have to build a prediction model for forecasting clicks for the future. The time interval for prediction needs to be hourly.

My example time series:

```
 DateTime            Clicks


(06/23/13 00:00:00)  757
(06/23/13 01:00:00)  714
(06/23/13 02:00:00)  776
(06/23/13 03:00:00)  870
(06/23/13 04:00:00) 1263
(06/23/13 05:00:00) 1457
(06/23/13 06:00:00) 1621
(06/23/13 07:00:00) 1606
(06/23/13 08:00:00) 1779
(06/23/13 09:00:00) 1832
(06/23/13 10:00:00) 1808
(06/23/13 11:00:00) 1789
(06/23/13 12:00:00) 1907
(06/23/13 13:00:00) 2021
(06/23/13 14:00:00) 2018
(06/23/13 15:00:00) 1836
(06/23/13 16:00:00) 1627
(06/23/13 17:00:00) 1331
(06/23/13 18:00:00) 1059
(06/23/13 19:00:00)  817
(06/23/13 20:00:00)  761
(06/23/13 21:00:00)  781
(06/23/13 22:00:00)  752
(06/23/13 23:00:00)  725
(06/24/13 00:00:00)  708
(06/24/13 01:00:00)  718
(06/24/13 02:00:00)  791
(06/24/13 03:00:00)  857
(06/24/13 04:00:00) 1094
(06/24/13 05:00:00) 1247
(06/24/13 06:00:00) 1316
(06/24/13 07:00:00) 1401
(06/24/13 08:00:00) 1575
(06/24/13 09:00:00) 1604
(06/24/13 10:00:00) 1774
(06/24/13 11:00:00) 1865
(06/24/13 12:00:00) 1964
(06/24/13 13:00:00) 2002
(06/24/13 14:00:00) 2043
(06/24/13 15:00:00) 2030
(06/24/13 16:00:00) 1733
(06/24/13 17:00:00) 1420
(06/24/13 18:00:00) 1075
(06/24/13 19:00:00)  831
(06/24/13 20:00:00)  789
(06/24/13 21:00:00)  791
(06/24/13 22:00:00)  715
(06/24/13 23:00:00)  683
(06/25/13 00:00:00)  802
(06/25/13 01:00:00)  811
(06/25/13 02:00:00)  838
(06/25/13 03:00:00)  851
(06/25/13 04:00:00) 1064
(06/25/13 05:00:00) 1191
(06/25/13 06:00:00) 1242
(06/25/13 07:00:00) 1233
(06/25/13 08:00:00) 1452
(06/25/13 09:00:00) 1501
(06/25/13 10:00:00) 1718
(06/25/13 11:00:00) 1861
(06/25/13 12:00:00) 1896
(06/25/13 13:00:00) 2073
(06/25/13 14:00:00) 2279
(06/25/13 15:00:00) 2239
(06/25/13 16:00:00) 2018
(06/25/13 17:00:00) 1550
(06/25/13 18:00:00) 1182
(06/25/13 19:00:00) 1063
(06/25/13 20:00:00)  973
(06/25/13 21:00:00) 1027
(06/25/13 22:00:00)  961
(06/25/13 23:00:00)  890
(06/26/13 00:00:00)  894
(06/26/13 01:00:00)  835
(06/26/13 02:00:00)  852
(06/26/13 03:00:00)  893
(06/26/13 04:00:00) 1111
(06/26/13 05:00:00) 1239
(06/26/13 06:00:00) 1263
(06/26/13 07:00:00) 1260
(06/26/13 08:00:00) 1451
(06/26/13 09:00:00) 1556
(06/26/13 10:00:00) 1733
(06/26/13 11:00:00) 1981
(06/26/13 12:00:00) 2063
(06/26/13 13:00:00) 2150
(06/26/13 14:00:00) 2278
(06/26/13 15:00:00) 2188
(06/26/13 16:00:00) 1980
(06/26/13 17:00:00) 1611
(06/26/13 18:00:00) 1381
(06/26/13 19:00:00) 1211
(06/26/13 20:00:00) 1129
(06/26/13 21:00:00) 1092
(06/26/13 22:00:00) 1009
(06/26/13 23:00:00)  973
(06/27/13 00:00:00)  865
(06/27/13 01:00:00)  805
(06/27/13 02:00:00)  840
(06/27/13 03:00:00)  813
(06/27/13 04:00:00) 1010
(06/27/13 05:00:00) 1201
(06/27/13 06:00:00) 1329
(06/27/13 07:00:00) 1343
(06/27/13 08:00:00) 1532
(06/27/13 09:00:00) 1612
(06/27/13 10:00:00) 1768
(06/27/13 11:00:00) 1977
(06/27/13 12:00:00) 2089
(06/27/13 13:00:00) 2247
(06/27/13 14:00:00) 2270
(06/27/13 15:00:00) 2275
(06/27/13 16:00:00) 2155
(06/27/13 17:00:00) 1639
(06/27/13 18:00:00) 1315
(06/27/13 19:00:00) 1099
(06/27/13 20:00:00) 1052
(06/27/13 21:00:00) 1099
(06/27/13 22:00:00)  965
(06/27/13 23:00:00)  961
(06/28/13 00:00:00)  765
(06/28/13 01:00:00)  830
(06/28/13 02:00:00)  874
(06/28/13 03:00:00)  845
(06/28/13 04:00:00) 1011
(06/28/13 05:00:00) 1160
(06/28/13 06:00:00) 1232
(06/28/13 07:00:00) 1310
(06/28/13 08:00:00) 1467
(06/28/13 09:00:00) 1639
(06/28/13 10:00:00) 1704
(06/28/13 11:00:00) 3704
(06/28/13 12:00:00) 7350
(06/28/13 13:00:00) 7629
(06/28/13 14:00:00) 7570
(06/28/13 15:00:00) 7276
(06/28/13 16:00:00) 7189
(06/28/13 17:00:00) 7139
(06/28/13 18:00:00) 7167
(06/28/13 19:00:00) 6871
(06/28/13 20:00:00) 6575
(06/28/13 21:00:00) 6112
(06/28/13 22:00:00) 5276
(06/28/13 23:00:00) 4407
(06/29/13 00:00:00) 3741
(06/29/13 01:00:00) 3427
(06/29/13 02:00:00) 3311
(06/29/13 03:00:00) 3096
(06/29/13 04:00:00) 3010
(06/29/13 05:00:00) 3301
(06/29/13 06:00:00) 3783
(06/29/13 07:00:00) 4578
(06/29/13 08:00:00) 5599
(06/29/13 09:00:00) 6590
(06/29/13 10:00:00) 6998
(06/29/13 11:00:00) 7323
(06/29/13 12:00:00) 7282
(06/29/13 13:00:00) 7009
(06/29/13 14:00:00) 6636
(06/29/13 15:00:00) 6407
(06/29/13 16:00:00) 6386
(06/29/13 17:00:00) 6505
(06/29/13 18:00:00) 3104
(06/29/13 19:00:00)  939
(06/29/13 20:00:00)  915
(06/29/13 21:00:00)  955
(06/29/13 22:00:00)  968
(06/29/13 23:00:00)  870
(06/30/13 00:00:00) 3504
(06/30/13 01:00:00) 3122
(06/30/13 02:00:00) 2874
(06/30/13 03:00:00) 2613
(06/30/13 04:00:00) 2905
(06/30/13 05:00:00) 2806
(06/30/13 06:00:00) 3244
(06/30/13 07:00:00) 3789
(06/30/13 08:00:00) 5015
(06/30/13 09:00:00) 6031
(06/30/13 10:00:00) 6841
(06/30/13 11:00:00) 7014
(06/30/13 12:00:00) 7265
(06/30/13 13:00:00) 7460
(06/30/13 14:00:00) 7275
(06/30/13 15:00:00) 7531
(06/30/13 16:00:00) 7013
(06/30/13 17:00:00) 6637
(06/30/13 18:00:00) 5770
(06/30/13 19:00:00) 5593
(06/30/13 20:00:00) 6524
(06/30/13 21:00:00) 5081
(06/30/13 22:00:00) 1131
(06/30/13 23:00:00)  949
```

This is a time series for a whole week on a hourly basis. Considering this data I need to predict using Holt-Winters the number of clicks that will be obtained for the next hour i.e. (06/28/13 00:00:00). I am trying to figure it out but am getting really confused. I will be thankful if someone can point me to the right direction.

EDIT:

I am using the Holt-Winters predict module as follows:

```
search_fit <- HoltWinters(z)
p = predict(search_fit,24)
```

But the problem is that the HOLT-WINTERS is not detecting any trend in the prediction. is it normal? Because there is a big change starting 06/28/13.

Following are my predicted values:

```
Time Series:
Start = c(15887, 1) 
End = c(15887, 24) 
Frequency = 24 
            fit
 [1,]  927.6462
 [2,]  935.2716
 [3,] 1006.5636
 [4,] 1066.4182
 [5,] 1295.5852
 [6,] 1442.9397
 [7,] 1508.1693
 [8,] 1590.9613
 [9,] 1762.5033
[10,] 1789.1287
[11,] 1958.1083
[12,] 2049.1711
[13,] 2054.7757
[14,] 2168.1302
[15,] 2163.1514
[16,] 1979.5268
[17,] 1772.7355
[18,] 1483.0484
[19,] 1220.1946
[20,]  987.2366
[21,]  938.1745
[22,]  965.5915
[23,]  940.4669
[24,]  911.0089
```

and this is the prediction plot.
[image]

The trend component shows no variation. There is something I might be doing wrong while using the predict method of Holt-Winters.

Comment: "Here's my data. How do I analyze it?" is too broad. What, specifically, are you confused about? What did you try? Also, see [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry about that. I am confused in the predict method of HoltWinters. I am not sure as how to use the time interval for this module.

Answer (score 4):

**Here are some suggestions/things to try:**

One reason you are not seeing `HoltWinters` pick up a trend could be that the change you are referring to (on 6/28/13 in your data) is manifesting itself in the *level* component. The clicks have changed *materially* starting from noon on 6/28.

One note: `HoltWinters()` will spit out the Smoothing parameters (alpha, beta, gamma). It will give you the slope b. If *beta* is 0, that only means that the trend *does not change* over the time series. It started with a slope b, and continues to be at the same slope.

**Things to try**

Try this:

```
 > library(forecast)
 > accuracy(search_fit)
```

Also a good idea to check the auto-correlations:

```
 > acf(search_fit$residuals, lag.max=24)
```

#### A few general comments that might help your analysis

- In addition to HoltWinters (exponential smoothing), you might want to look into ARIMA methods.
  As Rob Hyndman states at the start of Chapter 8 of his textbook:

> Expo­nen­tial smooth­ing and ARIMA mod­els are the two most
>   widely-used approaches to time series fore­cast­ing, and pro­vide
>   com­ple­men­tary approaches to the prob­lem. While expo­nen­tial
>   smooth­ing mod­els were based on a descrip­tion of trend and
>   sea­son­al­ity in the data, ARIMA mod­els aim to describe the
>   auto­cor­re­la­tions in the data.

- As a quick starting reference I find 1.Avril Coghlan's [Little Book of R for Time series](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
  to be a great primer. Also, 2. [Time Series Analysis with R - Part I](http://www.statoek.wiso.uni-goettingen.de/veranstaltungen/zeitreihen/sommer03/ts_r_intro.pdf)  is great, with a little more technical detail.
- As and when you find the time, reading Prof. Rob Hyndman's book [**Forecasting Principles and Practice** online](http://otexts.com/fpp/) is well worth the time, for anyone who's going to be doing Time Series analysis.
- Be sure to try the `forecast` package as well. Especially its `auto.arima()` function is an incredible time saver.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Narasimhan. I will sure check it out and tell you about my findings

Answer (score 0):

Try auto.arima or ets for automated time series
See code here
http://rpubs.com/newajay/timeseries